# alter table mysql en postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Estoy intentando hacer hacer esta modificación de MySQL a postgresql:

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(id_autor) REFERENCES autores (id_autor) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(id_documento) REFERENCES documentos(id_documento) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Esta en MySQL y necesito hacer eso mismo en postgresql.

Comment: Pero... ¿ya tienes las tablas `documento_autor`, `autores` y  `documentos` creadas en Postgresql? ¿Con los mismos nombres de columnas que aparecen aquí? ¿Ya tienen datos? Deberías decirlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Si ya tengo esas tablas con los campos y mismo tipo de dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las restricciones que incluyen `ON DELETE CASCADE` tienen un tratamiento especial:

#### Caso 1: Si no existe la restricción

Debería funcionarte como la tienes

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor
FOREIGN KEY (id_autor)
REFERENCES autores(id_autor)
ON DELETE CASCADE  ON UPDATE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor_documento 
FOREIGN KEY(id_documento) 
REFERENCES documentos(id_documento) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

#### Caso 2: Si la restricción existe, debes borrarla antes de crearla

Supongamos que la restricción de la tabla `documento_autor` se llama `fk_documento_autor`

Primero la borras:

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor;
```

Luego se crea de nuevo:

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor
FOREIGN KEY (id_autor)
REFERENCES autores(id_autor)
ON DELETE CASCADE  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Ahora vamos con la otra restricción:

Si la restricción se llama `fk_documento_autor_documento`

Primero la borras:

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor_documento;
```

Luego se crea de nuevo:

```
ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor_documento 
FOREIGN KEY(id_documento) 
REFERENCES documentos(id_documento) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Nota:** Si la tabla tiene datos y no cumplen con las restricciones que quieres añadir, no será posible crearlas de esta manera, tendrás que deshabilitar las FK, crear las tablas y luego habilitarlas, o más bien revisar los datos, para no tener datos insertados que violen las restricciones.

Comment: Gracias, me podrías explicar esta también la debo ejecutar?:

ALTER TABLE documento_autor
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_documento_autor_documento 
FOREIGN KEY(id_documento) 
REFERENCES documentos(id_documento) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Comment: Es que no entiendo esta sintaxis: fk_documento_autor_documento. Se lo agradecería ya que en la anterior fue fk_documento_autor.

Comment: @JohnVanegas Debes ejecutarla si quieres crear esa llave foránea entre `documento_autor` y `documentos`. Eso ya depende de tu diseño, yo respondí con los datos de tu pregunta. En cuanto a esto, `fk_documento_autor_documento` es el nombre de la llave foránea.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya le entiendo.